# Is there a KDE systray epplet for Enlightment?

Tags: linux, usability, opensuse, kde4

Enlightenment DR16 is packaged with openSUSE 11.1 but it's a bit painful to use with KDE apps as there's no obvious (on the Enlightenment site, google etc.) way to provide a systray for KDE apps that require one (e.g., ktorrent).

Anyone know of a way around this?

I'm not using e for the eye-candy - I'm running on a 2.6GHz Celeron and KDE (4.1) performance isn't exactly stellar so I'm trying out a few alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[trayer](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/x11/trayer) is a standalone system tray.  It should work regardless of what environment you're in, including e16.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Docker](http://icculus.org/openbox/2/docker/)

I don't know if it works with e16 but it works with Openbox which
is a good window manager for low end machines

Have you tried openbox in your "few alternatives"?